# How to change text in specific column in panda data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

What code should I use to delete the text /wiki/ from the WIKIURL column in the Panda dataframe below? Im kind of stuck.

DataFrame:

```
    WIKIURL                     NUMBER
0   /wiki/blabla                9
1   /wiki/bladiebla             8
2   /wiki/blablabla             1
3   /wiki/kipapapap             2
4   /wiki/wqeqrwtyee            3
5   /wiki/soduyfhlas            1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.str.replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) on the `WIKIURL` series. Example -

```
df['WIKIURL'] = df['WIKIURL'].str.replace('/wiki/','')
```

---

Demo -

```
In [95]: df
Out[95]:
            WIKIURL  NUMBER
0      /wiki/blabla       9
1   /wiki/bladiebla       8
2   /wiki/blablabla       1
3   /wiki/kipapapap       2
4  /wiki/wqeqrwtyee       3
5  /wiki/soduyfhlas       1

In [96]: df['WIKIURL'] = df['WIKIURL'].str.replace('/wiki/','')

In [97]: df
Out[97]:
      WIKIURL  NUMBER
0      blabla       9
1   bladiebla       8
2   blablabla       1
3   kipapapap       2
4  wqeqrwtyee       3
5  soduyfhlas       1
```

Comment: Thanks! Hate it to get stuck at something which is so easy to solve (in hindsight). :-(